# How to use a method of a class inside a callback function in actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, callback, event-listener

When you call a method of a class inside a callback function, you can not use `this` object.
To call the method, in javascript, I declare `that` variable, assign `this` to `that`, and use `that` inside the callback to call the method of `this`.

In actionscript, do I have to do the same way as I do in javascript?

The following code is the example to use `that` to call a method inside callback.
Are there more simple way in actionscript?

```
class C {
    private var that:C;

    function C() {
        that = this
    }

    public function f1():void {
        var sp:Sprite = new Sprite;

        sp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function():void {
            this.f2(); // this doesn't work
            that.f2(); // that works
        });
    }

    public function f2():void {
        trace('hello');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just ommit 'this' ?

Comment: @OXMO456 Thank you very much. Omitting `this` worked. It's very simple solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another way to do that:

```
package some.package {
    class SomeSprite extends Sprite {
        public function f1():void
        {
            var sprite1:Sprite = new Sprite;
            sprite1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,
                (new Closure(f2, this, ["Hello"], sprite1).handler));

            var sprite2:Sprite = new Sprite;
            sprite2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,
                (new Closure(f2, this, ["Bye Bye"], sprite2).handler));
        }

        private function f2(message:String):void
        {
            trace(message);
        }
    }
}

class Closure {
    public var callback:Function;
    public var thisObj:Object;
    public var params:Array;
    public var dispatcher:IEventDispatcher;
    public var cleanAfterCallback:Boolean = true;

    function Closure(callback:Function, thisObj:Object, 
        params:Array, dispatcher:IEventDispatcher)
    {
        this.callback = callback;
        this.thisObj = thisObj;
        this.params = params;
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }

    public function handler(e:Event):void
    {
        callback.apply(thisObj, params);

        if (cleanAfterCallback)
            dispatcher.removeEventListener(e.type, eventHandler)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a realy great solution if you actualy need to use a closure. If it is not so, you can create a custom class MySprite extends Sprite(). Then add a propperty "message" to this class, and in the method f1 you modify the code like sp1:MySprite = new MySprite(); sp1.message = "hello"; sp1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, callback); sp2:MySprite = new MySprite(); sp2.message = "good bye"; sp2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, callback); Now in the callback you can call f2(MySprite(event.target).message);

Answer (score 7):

If you make your callback function a method of the class C, you will be able to access `this`.

```
 public class C
 {
     private function f1():void
     {
         var sp:Sprite = new Sprite();

         sp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, callback);
     }

     private function callback(event:MouseEvent):void
     {
         this.f2();
     }

     private function f2():void
     {
         trace("Hello World");
     }
}
```

Now `this` refers to the instance of the class C and its scope is the whole class.

Comment: inline closures are dirty, dirty memory leaks as well

Comment: @Ivan Thanks for your useful information. 
I didn't know that. 
If `f2()` has parameter( `function f2(message:String):void { trace(message); }` ) and 
if I want to add f2('hello') to `sp1` and f2('good bye') to `sp2` as callback function, 
I think I have to define 2 callback methods, `private function callbak(event:MouseEvent):void { this.f2('hello'); }` and 
`private function callbak(event:MouseEvent):void { this.f2('good bye'); }`?
Is there better way to do that?

Comment: @divillysausages Thanks for information about inline closure memory leak.
If I assign an inline closure to a variable just before `addEventListener()` and use the variable for callback. 
For example, `var f:Function = function():void { that.f2(); }; sp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f);`,
Is this code also inline closure and does it cause memory leak? Or it is clean and safe?

Comment: @js_ I added an answer to explain why as the comment section isn't big enough :)

Answer (score 3):

See the [Function Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Function.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) on Adobe site. Use apply with "thisArg" equal to the object on which you want to invoke the member function and "this" will be correct.

Comment: Thanks. 
But I think `apply` can not be used for callback 
because `apply` executes function immediately instead of executing function when callback happens.

Comment: @js_ what **Fearnor** meant is what I wrote in the code snippet in my answer

Answer (score 2):

You are using an inline function closure, so the `this` you are looking for will not be in that scope. It is very similar (if not the same) to function closures in javascript. The above method is fine. There are other ways to do this but there are not necessarily simpler,  it depends on your implementation.

```
function():void {
        this.f2(); // this is scoped only to within this function
        that.f2(); // that has reference to the global object this
}
```

Please read the following in the ActionScript Documentation
[Function Closures](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=03_Language_and_Syntax_21.html)
[Event listeners](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=16_Event_handling_6.html#119732)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer, but is more to explain why inline closures are a memory leak, from a comment request by @js_.

Memory management in Flash is done 2 ways; reference counting and mark and sweep (check out http://divillysausages.com/blog/tracking_memory_leaks_in_as3 to go more in-depth).

The memory leak comes from the `addEventListener()` call. By default, `addEventListener` will create a reference to the object that it's listening to - as in, your anonymous function will hold a reference to your object.

You can make it a weak listener, but because your function is anonymous, it has no other references, meaning that if you event listener was weak, it'd all get collected at the end of the function (ditto if you used a local variable).

So, to make anonymous functions work, you need to make the event listener strong. But when you come to remove the listener, you can't get access to the anonymous function, so you can't remove it. Best case scenario, you lose the memory allocated for the callback. Worst case scenario, the reference to your object by the anonymous function means that the object itself never gets collected (which can chain) as Flash thinks it's still in use.

If the object itself eventually has no other references, other than the event listener, then both should get collected during the mark and sweep phase (as this was designed with such circular references in mind). That said, you never really want mark and sweep to kick in - it's slow as hell (you'll probably notice a pause every so often in your program) and only ever starts when your memory usage starts to get out of hand. You want to control reference counting yourself

Comment: Thanks. 
How about the following 2 ideas to avoid mark and sweep?
(1) I think overwriting sp with null or other object, for example, `sp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function():void { that.f2(); }); sp = null; or sp = anotherSprite;` also delete the reference to the anonimous function without calling removeEventListener().
(2) I can access anonimous function after addEventListener() by assining it to sp's member instead of a just variable, for example, `sp.f = function():void { that.f2(); }; sp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sp.f);` `sp.removeEventListener(sp.f);`

Comment: if you store the function in something like `sp.f`, then it's no longer anonymous ;) That's the general idea though. In all my classes, I implement a `destroy()` function where I clear up listeners, null references, clear arrays, dictionaries, remove graphics from the stage, call `destroy()` on any internal objects that implement it, etc. Each object is responsible for it's own clean up. So in your example, it'd be something like `sp.destroy(); sp = null;` There's a `MemoryTracker` class in the link I provided to help you see if objects are properly gone or not

Answer (score 0):

If you do a trace(this), it will say something like [function Global]. That is why it does not work.