# Dynamically passing parameters to event listeners AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a 16x16 grid of buttons, and want to add an event listener to each of them so when clicked it will return its unique grid position number (anything between 0-255);
What I have so far:

```
    public static const GRID_SIZE:Number = 16;
    private var i:int;
    private var j:int;

    // Constructor
    public function Grid()
    {
        for (i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE; j++)
            {
                // Creates new instance of GridButton, a custom class that extends SimpleButton
                var button:GridButton = new GridButton();

                // Arranges buttons into a grid
                button.x = (i + 1) * button.width;
                button.y = (j + 1) * button.height;

                // Create unique value for grid position
                var position:Number = i * GRID_SIZE + j;

                // Add listener to button, with position as extra param
                button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent) : void { buttonClick(e, position) } );

                // Adds button to Sprite
                addChild(button);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately every time the listener function is called by each button, it uses the last two values of i and j, which in this case return 255 for every button.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can also use Closures. Check my answer to the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396845/how-to-use-a-method-of-a-class-inside-a-callback-function-in-actionscript/7412402#7412402

Comment: Unless you fully understand the ramifications of using closures you should not use them.

Answer (score 2):

there are some other options...

**1**  use [signals](https://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals) instead of flash event listeners,  [here's a post](http://blog.tkassembled.com/83/) that describes it and gives more detail. Also a [video tutorial](http://johnlindquist.com/2010/01/21/as3-signals-tutorial/) to get you started quickly. The reason I'm suggesting this is that you can setup a signal to pass a parameter, so you don't need to use the event target, which doesn't always work the best.

**2**  use a function factory.

```
// factory:
public function fooFactory($mc:GridButton):Function{
    var $f:Function = new Function($e:MouseEvent):void{
        trace($mc.x, $mc.y);
    }
    // you might want to consider adding these to a dictionary or array, so can remove the listeners to allow garbage collection
    return $f;
}


// then assign the function to the button like this
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fooFactory(button) );
```

this does essentially what you wanted to do, but it will work because the `position` var is not changing. In your code the `position` is changing every time the loop executes, then when you you fire the listener function it uses the last value that `position` was assigned, which is why you are getting 255 for all of them. Let me know if that's not making sense...

Answer (score 1):

You could add a name to this button, for example `button.name = "button" + position;` and in event handler function you can extract position parameter from target name (`e.target.name`):

```
button.name = "button" + position;
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClick);
```

and event handler:

```
function buttonClick(e:MouseEvent) {
    var position:Number = Number(e.target.name.replace("button", ""));
    // ... do wathever you want with position parameter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get back the values of i and j from the same expression which is being used to assign x and y values to the buttons. For example:

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);

function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent) {
    var i:int   = (e.target.x / e.target.width) - 1;
    var j:int   = (e.target.y / e.target.height) - 1;

    var position:Number = i * GRID_SIZE + j;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked fine....i.e. clicking on different text fields traced different value.
The idea is to create a new reference to pos:Number so that even after updating pos, the closure still points to the old

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldType;

    public class AsDing extends Sprite
    {
        private static const GRID_SIZE:uint = 2;
        public function AsDing()
        {
            for(var i:uint=0; i<GRID_SIZE; i++)
            {
                for(var j:uint=0; j<GRID_SIZE; j++)
                {
                    var tf:TextField = new TextField();
                    var pos:Number = i*GRID_SIZE + j;
                    tf.text = pos.toString();
                    tf.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;
                    tf.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, createMCHdlr(pos));
                    addChild(tf);
                    tf.x = i*100; tf.y = j*100;
                }
            }
        }

        private function createMCHdlr(pos:Number):Function
        {
            var ret:Function = function(evt:MouseEvent):void
            {
                trace('pos: ' + pos);
            };
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using a variable from outer scope inside an anonymous function you got big trouble with closures and memory leak already: `position` is used in `function(e:MouseEvent)`, but it was created in `function Grid()`, so it'll obey `function Grid()`'s changes. And you're dealing with 256 `function(e:MouseEvent)`s that you added but can't remove, overheading memory!

Let's remake your code the simplest working way:

```
public static const GRID_SIZE:Number = 16;
private var i:int;
private var j:int;

public function Grid() {
  var functions:Object;

  for (i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < GRID_SIZE; j++) {
      var button:GridButton = new GridButton();
      button.x = (i + 1) * button.width;
      button.y = (j + 1) * button.height;
      var position:Number = i * GRID_SIZE + j;
      functions[position] = buttonClick(position);
      button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, functions[position]);
      //button.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, functions[position]);
      addChild(button);
    }
  }

  buttonClick(position:Number):Function {
    return function(e:MouseEvent):void {
      // Now you can use both unique "e" and "position" here for each button
    }
  }
}
```

Since you're adding 256 listeners, you have to store each in distinct variables (the list of properties `functions[position]` was made for it), so you can safely remove each one later **to free memory** in the same way you added them.

This was elaborated from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13488640/1837285).